# How to handle "[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" in JENKINS?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jenkins, heap-memory

I have been building GWT war file on Jenkins. In a specific "job" I have encountered an error which says `[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. As a solution, I have included an environment variable "MAVEN_OPTS" with a value of `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`. FYI, I have also tried 'echo' command prompt for MAVEN_OPTS and it displays the same value as I had given in the environment variable.

**MAVEN COMPILER PLUGIN in pom.xml :**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Full error: **

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13:51.518s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 29 13:06:25 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/989M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-              plugin:2.4.0:compile
(default) on project dpgwtwebapplication: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\jre\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath    "C:\U
```

Also in mvn.bat file, the value of MAVEN_OPTS is displaying as `-Xmx512m` as you can notice in last of Full error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is not to less memory for the java compile process but for the gwt-compiler. Increase the memory significantly here:
      
        org.codehaus.mojo
        gwt-maven-plugin
        ...

See: [Codehaus.org gwt plugin usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/compiler.html)

Comment: Thankyou @ChangeRequest. I just had to include `
    <extraJvmArgs>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</extraJvmArgs>` in Maven compiler plugin in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are forking the compiler as configured in the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/). You should define the parameters for memory like the following:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
          <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: I had given meminitial as 512m and maxmem as 1024m. But its still giving the same error as before.

Comment: So you have to increase the memore more, but it sounds like you need to take a look into the code which is really causing the problem.